# Streaming media content between Android and IOS devices

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, streaming, a2dp

I would like to implement this scenario:
- one IOS device and one Android device;
- the first simply exposes it's media library to the Android one (connected through BT);
- the second accesses the first's media library and plays with its contents.

I've been looking throught IOS/Android Official documentation and searching online for clean solutions, but it's said everywhere that a2dp (which is the standard BT protocol used for the streaming of media contents) isn't supported natively by Android OS, so that I can't hope in a clean solution.

Could you help me? Or the only possibility i've got is implementing a self-made protocol with buffering and all the other stuff?

PLEASE NOTE!! I'm not asking you to write the application for me, I would only like to know if anybody knows something more about this.

Comment: Andrea, did you anywhere with this idea?